# How do I set the resolution when converting dot files (graphviz) to images?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I tried

```
$ dot -Tpng rel_graph.gv > rel_graph.png
```

but the resulting image has a very low quality.

Answer (score 107):

Use the dpi attribute.

Example:

```
graph G { 
  graph [ dpi = 300 ]; 
  /* The rest of your graph here. */ 
}
```

Comment: The negative side of this approach is that there is absolutely no anti-aliasing produced. With low resolution (like 72 dpi, for example) your output image will look very "dotted"

Comment: @yegor256 maybe they changed over the time, I see anti-aliasing on both 72 dpi and 300 dpi.

Comment: @einpoklum yes it does

Comment: The equivalent `-Gdpi=300` on the command line is also useful in some situations.

Answer (score 60):

> dot -Tpng -Gdpi=300 foo.gv > foo110percent.png

Use option -Gdpi.

You can find more information [here](http://www.graphviz.org/faq/#FaqQuality).

Comment: `dot -Tpng -Gdpi=300 foo.gv -o foo110percent.png`

Note: You can change the output format by varying the extension of the filename specified with `-o`
see: http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/output.html

Answer (score 13):

I find GraphViz draws nice Graphs but the resolution tends to be reasonably low, you could try outputting to SVG and then using some other image package to scale the image  appropriately and then save to a pixel based format like PNG.  This might give you better resolution but I've never tried it personally, I tend to mainly just create SVG files I can then view with a browser.

Just change the -T parameter to -Tsvg

```
dot -Tsvg rel_graph.gv > rel_graph.svg
```

There is some stuff in the Dot Guide http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf about scaling of Graphs but it's not very clear about how that affects resolution, you could also experiment with those settings and see if that improves things.

Comment: Saving the SVG data to a `*.png` file seems like a *bad* idea to me…

Comment: @MvG Dumb typo on my part, think I copy pasted this from the OP question and didn't do a full `png` to `svg` change

Answer (score 0):

I think antialiasing is driver-dependent. For example, we hardcode
cairo_font_options_set_antialias(options,CAIRO_ANTIALIAS_GRAY);
but I don't see anything about explicit smoothing or antialiasing in other graphics primitives or any mention of antialiasing or smoothing in any other drivers.