# graphviz plot too wide

Tags: python, jupyter, graphviz

I'm doing a practice exercise of creating a decision tree using graphviz in jupyter notebook. however, the decision tree is coming too wide. here is the code:

```
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
export_graphviz(tree, out_file="tree.dot", class_names=["malignant", "benign"], 
                feature_names=cancer.feature_names, impurity=False, filled=True)
with open("tree.dot") as f:
    dot_graph = f.read()
display(graphviz.Source(dot_graph))
```

and I get this:
[image]

I have to scroll to see the left side of the decision tree. can I make the width smaller? how?

Comment: can this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428448/reducing-the-size-as-in-area-of-the-graph-generated-by-graphviz

Comment: Can you set rankdir to LR - see if the graph gets generated from left to right instead of top to bottom.  I know how to do this directly but not from python.

Answer (score 3):

If the node tree is spreading widely, you can try

- add line breaks for long labels (`node1 [label="line\nbreak"]`)
- reduce nodes width and margin globally (`node [width=0.1 margin=0]`)
- reduce distance between nodes in row for graph ([`graph [nodesep=0.1]`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/nodesep/))
- reduce graph size ([`graph [size="3,3"]`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/size/))

Or you can put all the nodes in a column with `rankdir=LR; edge[constraint=false]`, as in  example below.
Image:
[image: node column made with graphviz dot]
Script:

```
digraph {
    graph [rankdir=LR ranksep=1]
    
    node[shape=box width=3]
    edge[constraint=false]
    
    A -> {B C}
    B -> {D E}
    C -> F
    D -> {G H}
    E -> I
    F -> {J T}
    G -> {K L}
    H -> {M N}
    J -> {O P}
}
```

---

Related question: [Is it possible to generate a small GraphViz chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68321537/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-small-graphviz-chart)