# using dot in orgmode to create latex-pdf, how can I set the grap size?

Tags: pdf, emacs, org-mode, dot

How can I set the graph or image size in my generated pdf?

Using this code in org-mode:

```
 #+BEGIN_SRC dot :file hallo1_1_1.png 
 digraph hallo1_1_1 {
  A [shape = "circle",style=filled, fillcolor=yellow];
  }
  #+END_SRC
```

A giant page filling yellow pixeled circle is drawn. 
How can I set image size and resolution?
Thank you.

Comment: It's probably better to have dot generate the shape at a large size and then use the `attr_latex` mechanism in the answer to shrink it. That will avoid the pixelation that you observed. But you might have to increase the thickness of the boundary, which might become a bit ragged otherwise. Something like this should work: `A [shape = "circle", width=10, penwidth=2, style=filled, fillcolor=yellow];`

Comment: Got the resolution solution found :D. [Link -> StackOverFlow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286813/how-do-i-set-the-resolution-when-converting-dot-files-graphviz-to-images)

Comment: Got the resolution solution found. [Link -> StackOverFLow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286813/how-do-i-set-the-resolution-when-converting-dot-files-graphviz-to-images)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always add specific LaTeX (or HTML) attributes to the result of a source block:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC dot :file hallo1_1_1.png 
 digraph hallo1_1_1 {
  A [shape = "circle",style=filled, fillcolor=yellow];
  }
#+END_SRC

#+attr_latex: :width 2cm
#+RESULTS:
[[file:hallo1_1_1.png]]
```

Documentation [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Images-in-LaTeX-export.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I never would have got the idea for changing the png. Normaly I generetate the pdf by running "c-c e" on the whole org-file. In that case the #+RESULTS section would not show up. Thanks. Now I just added the #RESULT section  to my "dot" snippet (If you know what I mean).  Problem solved

Comment: You don't need to add the `#RESULT` section manually; just `C-c C-c` on the source code block and it appears (and you can click on the image link to see it).

Answer (score 0):

You can set dpi option in header.

```
#+headers: :file file.gif :cmdline -Tgif -Gdpi=100
#+begin_src dot
 digraph g { 
...
}
#+end_src
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I was unable to set the resolution.

Comment: Got the resolution solution found.  [Link -> StackOverFLow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286813/how-do-i-set-the-resolution-when-converting-dot-files-graphviz-to-images